# Periodical dump of SQL Server table to Oracle table

Tags: sql-server, oracle, dump

I have a request to dump periodically, every 15 minutes, data from a SQL Server database and move it to an Oracle database.

This activity will go under a scheduler like Tivoli.

Have Oracle or SQL Server some way to do this? Or, is there some product or workaround to satisfy this request?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Are you aware of [SQL Server replication?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) sounds like a good starting point

Comment: I don't know this product. Is there some reference to use with a scheduler?

Comment: It's a job scheduling tool, schedule a windows OS task to run the dtexec.exe process against the package. This [MSDN question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/635436e4-a53d-4b48-b351-651d0b514c3c) suggests reviewing the Tivoli documentation for how to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I investigate this solution. Thanks.

Comment: If the client owns SQL Server 2005+, they are licensed for SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up [replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) from SQL Server with an [Oracle subscriber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151738%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx). This will keep the Oracle table up to date in real-time, changes applied to the SQL Server table are immediately applied to the Oracle table as well.